# matplotlib, how to plot 3d 2 variable function under given conditions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Plotting the function:
(x1 - 3)^2 + (x2 - 2)^2

With constraints:

- x1^2 - x2 - 3 <= 0
- x2 - 1 <= 0
- -x1 <= 0

The equation can also be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lD71.png).

I am trying to solve this graphically using matplotlib

[image: graph missing the first condition]

but ended up with the above graph using the code below ([the question i found that helped me with the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881812/trying-to-plot-multivariate-function-in-3d-matplotlib-returns-empty-figure)) which is missing the first condition.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange
from pylab import meshgrid

# function to be plotted
def z_func(a, b):
    return (a - 3) * (a - 3) + (b - 2) * (b - 2)

x1 = arange(15.0, 0, -0.1) # x1 >= 0 according to given conditions
x2 = arange(-15.0, 1, 0.1) # x2 <= 1 according to given conditions
X1,X2 = meshgrid(x1, x2)
Z = z_func(X1, X2)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.RdBu,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))

ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z-axis')
ax.view_init(elev=25, azim=-120)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```

in which way shall the above code be altered in order to also take the first condition into account?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter the array to plot and set all values outside the condition to `nan`:

```
Z[X1**2 - X2 - 3 > 0] = np.nan
```

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from pylab import meshgrid

# function to be plotted
def z_func(a, b):
    return (a - 3) * (a - 3) + (b - 2) * (b - 2)

x1 = np.arange(15.0, 0, -0.1) # x1 >= 0 according to given conditions
x2 = np.arange(-15.0, 1, 0.1) # x2 <= 1 according to given conditions
X1,X2 = meshgrid(x1, x2)
Z = z_func(X1, X2)
# set all values outside condition to nan
Z[X1**2 - X2 - 3 > 0] = np.nan

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(X1, X2, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,vmin=0, vmax=np.nanmax(Z), 
                       cmap=plt.cm.RdBu,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.set_xlabel('x-axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y-axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z-axis')
ax.view_init(elev=25, azim=-120)
ax.set_ylim(0,4)
fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
plt.show()
```